# Paste Values & Source formatting doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy data from a pivot table to a new sheet as a common data in vba. I want to preserve formatting of the pivot table (tab delimiter of subitems, bold font of groups and so on).
It is working correctly when I manually copy the pivot table and paste it with "Values & Source formatting" button.
When I record macro of function described above I get this code:

```
Sub Macro()
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

But when I use this macro in my code (Selection is replaced by a range) then data is copied but without format.

Here is my code:

```
Set sh = WB1.Sheets("RESULT")
WB1.Sheets("PIVOT").Range("A1:D" & lRow).Copy
sh.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
    , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
sh.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
sh.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone _
, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
sh.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone _
, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pivot Table Formatting

- Copy the code into a standard module (e.g. `Module1`).
- Adjust the **const**ants including the **workbook**.
- I'm afraid this is the closest I could get. All other solutions I've tried including the one you mentioned give you a copy of the Pivot Table, not a 'free' range.

**Interesting Links**

- [TableRange1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.tablerange1)
- [TableRange2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.tablerange2)
- [TableStyle2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.tablestyle2)

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub pastePivotTable()
    
    ' Source
    Const srcName As String = "PIVOT"
    Const pivName As String = "PivotTable1"
    ' Target
    Const tgtName As String = "RESULT"
    Const tgtFirst As String = "A1"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim piv As PivotTable: Set piv = wb.Worksheets(srcName).PivotTables(pivName)
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = wb.Worksheets(tgtName).Range(tgtFirst)
    piv.TableRange1.Copy
    rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   
End Sub
```